# Referencing most recently added worksheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

My macro runs when a button on the instructions worksheet is clicked.  It is set to run on data that must be added as a worksheet to the workbook from another workbook.

However, I am not sure what the name of the worksheet will be once it is added.  Is there a way for my macro to run on the most recently added worksheet rather than looking for a particular worksheet name?

I was envisioning the end user right clicking the worksheet tab and copying the entire worksheet in.  In this case, the name would be Sheet1.  However, they may create a new tab whose name I wouldn't know and copy and paste from the data worksheet into this new tab.

My macro currently activates Sheet1, and then macro is run on this worksheet.  However, it is possible that the user may create a new worksheet named Sheet2 or Data, etc.  In this case, the macro would not find Sheet1.

Is there a way that the macro could find the newest worksheet rather than looking for a worksheet name?

```
Dim datasheet As String, location As String, col As String, row As String
Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Integer, LastCol As Integer, lCol As Integer
Dim t As Long, LasRow As Long, LasCol As Long
Dim t As Long, LasRow As Long, LasCol As Long
Dim PSheet As Worksheet, DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range

' Don't show macro as the macro runs
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
datasheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'Moves active sheet to end of active workbook.
ActiveSheet.Move _
After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: You can refer to the worksheet's index as well - `Worksheets(1).Activate` and even use a Loop to switch from one to the other.

Comment: If you want to find the last worksheet, you can use this - `Worksheet(Worksheets.Count).Activate`

Comment: Maybe we are overthinking this.  Maybe you could just use an `Application.InputBox` to ask the user to point to a range on the sheet they want to process.  e.g. `Set DSheet = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a cell on your data sheet", Type:=8).Worksheet`

Comment: That seems like a very practical idea.  I will give that a try.  Thanks!

Comment: Working around what @YowE3K suggested, you can have an inputBox to ask for the worksheetIndex. Another way is to have a `Public const sheetName as string` and trigger to populate it with the sheet name when a sheet is added into the workbook, I think that would be the easiest way (albeit, not particularly efficient).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you do not change the various worksheets' **codenames**, the last worksheet added should have the highest numerical codename, even if other worksheets have been deleted.

```
dim w as long, lw as long, wsn as string
for w = 1 to worksheets.count
    if clng(replace(worksheets(w).codename, "Sheet", vbnullstring)) > lw then
        lw = int(replace(worksheets(w).codename, "Sheet", vbnullstring))
        wsn = worksheets(w).name
    end if
next w

with worksheets(wsn)
    'do stuff with the last added worksheet
end with
```

If worksheets can be deleted then you might want to double-check that the codename sequence does not restart after closing and reopening the workbook. **addendum:** Yes, the codename of a deleted worksheet will be reused if the workbook is closed and reopened.

This method should disregard where the latest worksheet has been copied to in the worksheets queue.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @YowE3K. Appreciated.

Comment: There is one downside to the code - the user must go into VBE before it will run successfully.  E.g. add the code to a workbook, save that workbook, close Excel, open Excel, open the workbook, add some sheets, run the macro (without opening VBE!) and you will get a type mismatch because `worksheets(w).codename` is `""`.

Comment: Hmmm. I do not require closing the workbook and reopening before reading  a newly added codename but I did it on a workbook that had been previously saved (i.e. not untitled).

Comment: Codenames are not added to sheets until the VBE is active so normally, when we develop stuff, adding a new sheet will automatically create its codename.  But an end-user won't normally activate the VBE at any stage and therefore the only codenames that will exist are the ones for the sheets that existed when the developer developed the code and saved the workbook with those codenames.  New sheets created by the user will still have an empty string for their codename.

Comment: OK, I'll bite. Running the code implicitly 'activates' the VBE. I just closed my test workbook, opened it, copied a few worksheets to various places in the queue then ran the code and it came up with the correct 'last' worksheet (without actually opening the VBE).

Comment: You have to (a) create new worksheets *while in an instance of Excel where you haven't opened the VBE at any stage*, and (b) make sure you run the macros without opening the VBE, e.g. by using Alt-F8 to bring up the macro selection screen, or by having a button associated with the macro.

Comment: @Jeeped: this won't work as-is with international versions of Excel where "Sheet" will be e.g. "Feuil" in French, etc. Besides, as mentioned by @YowE3K, worksheets added using `.Worksheets.Add` don't get a codename; those copied around do.

Comment: @Excelosaurus "those copied around do" - pedantically that should be "those copied *from a sheet that has a codename* will have a new codename allocated, but those copied from a sheet that has not yet been assigned a codename will not have a codename allocated to them"

Comment: @YowE3K not pedantic whatsoever; it's an important point that my comment missed. Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone used the worksheet `CustomProperties` property?  Can something be done using that in a `Workbook_NewSheet` event?  And then use that instead of `CodeName`?

Comment: @cyboashu Sigh :(

Answer (score 0):

In the ThisWorkbook module, add:

```
Public sheetName As String

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

Then look for `sheetName` in your code.

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
```

---

@cyboashu is right, this doesn't work when copying a sheet from another workbookk.

You can try this, it first populates an array with the names of the sheets when the workbook is opened. Then, when you run your macro it looks for each sheetName in that array and, if not found, then that worksheet was added after opening the file.
Insert this in your workbook module:

```
Public arrBase

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim i As Integer
    ReDim arrBase(1 To Sheets.Count)
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        arrBase(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next
End Sub

Sub ActivateNewSheet()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        found = Not IsInArray(Sheets(i).Name, arrBase)
        If found Then Sheets(i).Activate: Exit For
    Next

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: @cyboashu You're right, this makes it considerably more complicated.

Comment: Not trying to split the hair, but what happens when I rename a sheet ? :)

Comment: It assumes the renamed sheet is a new sheet and works with that one - that is, I'm dumb and didn't think of that ;^)

Comment: I spoke with my boss, and we are going to add to our instructions and have the person using the sheet name the new worksheet "Transfers."   If the they don't change the sheet name or spell it wrong, they will get a message box instructing them to change the name to "Transfers" and the sub will end.

Thank you to everyone who helped out on this problem.  I am grateful.